# OpenLayers Display One Icon for Multiple Icons based on Zoom Level

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am displaying a lot of points on my map and quite honestly it can slow your computer a lot depending on your zoom level. I am wondering if there is a function that I can call/create that will clump multiple icons and display only one, as to increase performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a cluster source https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: You want a Clusterer: [example from the latest documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html)

Comment: An other example with nice animation: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/map/map.clustering.html